# Grunt-ngmin: is it possible to replace old files to new ones?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, ngmin

I'm using [grunt-ngmin](https://github.com/btford/grunt-ngmin) to convert AngularJS DI.

I wonder: is it possible to replace old files with new ones without saving them to another location?

Comment: It is possible, but bot always desirable, as the output is not always 
what you'd expect it to be: for instance: controllers that are declared as simple functions won't be converted.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, you can use a grunt config looking something like this (if you want to replace all javascript files in the static folder):

```
ngmin: {
    dist: {
        expand: true,
        cwd: './static/',
        src: ['**/*.js'],
        dest: './static/'
    }
}
```

Be careful that you really want to replace the files though, might want to check the output first, if you haven't done so already.